# scrollbar change color and trackpiece when entering a new section css html js

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is it possible to manipulate the scrollbar when entering different sections of my page with js?
so if it enters a new section on the html page; tertiary color should switch with primary color.

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 0.5rem;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background-color: var(--primary-color);
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: var(--tertiary-color);
    border-radius: 10px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece {
    background-color: var(--primary-color);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

a simple example for scroll detected:
https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_event_scroll